# Probability with Alice and Betty

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> When Alice spends the day with the babysitter, there is a $0.6$ probability that she turns on the TV and watches a show. Her little sister Betty cannot turn on the TV by herself. But once the TV is on, Betty watches with probability $0.8$. Tomorrow the girls spend the day with the babysitter.
>
> a) What is the probability that both Alice and Betty watch TV tomorrow?
>
> b) What is the probability that Betty watches TV tomorrow?
>
> c) What is the probability that only Alice watches TV?

Define events $A,B$ as the event that Alice turns on the TV and watches a show, and the event that Betty watches TV.

Then for a), we get $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=0.6\cdot 0.8=0.48.$

For b), we have $P(A|B)=1,$ so that $P(B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A|B)}=\frac{0.48}{1}=0.48.$

For c), we need to find $P(A|B^{C})=\frac{P(A\cap B^{C})}{P(B^{C})}= \frac{1-0.48}{1-0.48}=1.$

---

Is any of the above correct? Thank you for time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) and b) are correct. Since Betty can't watch TV unless Alice does, the probabilities should be the same.

For c), you want $P(A\cap B^c)$, not $P(A\mid B^c)$. Now $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=0.6-0.48=0.12$.

Answer (score 0):

For C) It will be 0.6 * 0.2 = 0.12 rest seems correct

Here 0.2 will be the probability of Betty not watching the TV (i.e 1-0.8)

Comment: While this is correct, explaining where you got the $0.2$ from might help the asker more :)